# Flatbuffer Verifier not working?

Tags: c++, serialization, c++14, flatbuffers

I have the following test example FlatBuffers Schema:

```
namespace test;
struct Vec3 {
  x:float;
  y:float;
  z:float;
}
table Test {
  pos:[Vec3] (id:0);
}
root_type Test;
```

When I code a simple test, the verifier returns `false`, which I dont understand. The data seems correct...?

```cpp
#include <flatbuffers/flatbuffers.h>
#include "testbuffer_generated.h"

namespace t = test;
unsigned int n = 1; // How many positions we store

flatbuffers::FlatBufferBuilder builder;
std::vector<t::Vec3> vecs(n, t::Vec3(1, 3, 4));
auto vecsOffsets = builder.CreateVectorOfStructs(vecs.data(), vecs.size());

auto testBuilder = t::TestBuilder(builder);
testBuilder.add_pos(vecsOffsets);
auto test = testBuilder.Finish();
builder.Finish(test);

uint8_t* file    = builder.GetBufferPointer();
std::size_t size = builder.GetSize();
flatbuffers::Verifier v(file, size);
std::cout << t::VerifyTestBuffer(v); << std::endl;
```

I am using the master branch from https://github.com/google/flatbuffers

Anybody knows what might be wrong?

Comment: Please do not tag your C++ questions as C, they are not the same programming languages.

Comment: The code you show does not compile in C, don't show a C tag unless you are using C.

Comment: From just reading the code, it looks correct, and indeed it shouldn't fail. Try doing a `#define FLATBUFFERS_DEBUG_VERIFICATION_FAILURE` right above all includes, and you should get an assert whose callstack gives you a hint as what thing it was reading when it failed.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that out :-)

Comment: ok it fails because I have an additional `file_identifier "EXGR";` ->
shouldnt it not fail, also when I not write the file identifier as in the above code, if it shouldn't fail but it does then its a bug